# Trouble installing Ganache on fresh WSL

Tags: npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, audit, ganache, npm-vulnerabilities

I'm new to coding. I'm using Windows10 and just installed a WSL. I want to install Ganache using the command `npm install -g ganache-cli` but it says it has 8 vulnerabilities (7 moderate,1 high)

When I write `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` it says that there are no vulnerabilities. I don't understand where the problem is.

My NPM version is 8.3.0

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason to be alarmed about the vulnerabilities npm report, especially for a new project. Most of the time, these vulnerabilities won't actually affect your project. Be careful using `npm audit fix` especially `npm audit fix --force` because it can upgrade or downgrade packages, affecting functionality. If you do use it and it says 0 vulnerabilities after, that means it fixed all of them.

Packages are open-sourced so the community would spot any damaging or sneaky code, especially popular packages such as ganache-cli.

Read more here: https://www.voitanos.io/blog/don-t-be-alarmed-by-vulnerabilities-after-running-npm-install/

Comment: OK thanks for your answer, so how do i install ganache ignoring the vulnerabilities?

Comment: You just install it. The vulnerabilities will still be there but you can still use the package unless it gives an actual error.